# My MariaDB MYSQL query is returning results when it shouldn't

Tags: mysql, sql

here is my query -

```
SELECT column_one FROM generation1 UNION SELECT column_one FROM generation2 WHERE column_one = value;
```

I am trying to query both tables for the value and i want PHP to execute a block of code if no result is found but the value in the where condition returns a result even when the value doesn't exist on both tables.

Pls how can I make this query work and return the value of the "where" condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the `WHERE` logic to apply to the entire result set generated by the union query.  If so, then you should subquery and apply the filter there:

```sql
SELECT column_one
FROM
(
    SELECT column_one FROM generation1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT column_one FROM generation2
) t
WHERE column_one = value;
```

Comment: oh wow, this sounds like it will work. I guess the "t" there is a typo (i'll exclude and see). Thanks so much

Comment: @Zuby The `t` is certainly not a typo.  Take it out and see that the query will fail.  Every derived table in SQL generally requires an alias.

Comment: the "t" isn't a typo o! Without the "t" it didn't work. I need to learn more mehn! Thanks so so so much. It works.

Comment: Pls if I may ask, what does the t stand for? why does it have to be there?

Comment: @Zuby The `t` is called an _alias_, and you may use any name you wish.